# Conditional Format Based on color code

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I need to conditional format background color of Columns O:Y based on the color code AF:AK, is there a conditional format formula, or VBA code I can use.

Please ignore current format on columns O:X

[image]

Comment: @pnuts I am referencing another sheet and the color is white according to Function GetColor(x As Range) As Integer
GetColor = x.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
VBA

Comment: How many different colour codes do you use and how is the number generated? There may be another way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @pnuts not all cells are white fill this is only a portion of the data other colors include 43, 44

Comment: @Rob In total about 5 colors are to be generated which include 43,44,-4142 etc. and the colors are generated from another sheet using VBA code GetColor(x As Range) As Integer GetColor = x.Interior.ColorIndex End Function

Comment: Ignore the fact that the numbers are actually colour codes and use the normal conditional formatting rules to test the values in these cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the background colour to match the numbers directly in those cells with conditional formatting, though it is possible using VBA.

However, it is easier to check the value of the cells using the standard Conditional formatting rules and set the colours manually. This means you can have any colour matched to any number. Of course, you can choose the correct colour to fill if this is important to the solution.

I have set this up on a sheet below. I put the conditional formatting formula in the first cell (removing the $ symbol the system puts in for you) and copy across and down.

[image: Conditional Formatting]